# Colei che {patisce,teme} il caldo

Tags: vocabulary

Colei che {patisce,teme} gli spazi aperti = agorafobica,
Colei che {patisce,teme} i ragni = aracnofobica,
Colei che {patisce,teme} il caldo = ??.

Comment: Non mi risulta che si dica in questo senso, ma esiste “[termofobico](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/termofobico/)” (e “[termofobia](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/termofobia/)”), in ambito biologico, detto di organismi che non tollerano le alte temperature.

Comment: @DaG Mi piace. Se vuoi rispondere…

Comment: @DaG E poi, la parola che cerco mi serve PROPRIO per qualificare un organismo che non sopporta le alte temperature ;-) — anzi, l'ho già adoperata.

Comment: Benissimo! Lo scrivo subito come risposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dipende dal contesto in cui ti serve esprimere questo concetto. Sicuramente esiste “[termofobico](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/termofobico/)” (e “[termofobia](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/termofobia/)”), in ambito biologico, per parlare di organismi che non tollerano le alte temperature.